# No me funciona JavaFX en el IDE Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

qué tal? Estoy queriendo utilizar JavaFX en eclipse. No tengo ningún problema en agregar los .jar pertenecientes al lib que viene en la carpeta que se descarga de JavaFX (OpenJFX 20.0.1) al classpath, ni tampoco al instalar SceneBuilder.

El problema se basa específicamente en que Eclipse (Version 2023-03 con el  no me detecta que tenga instalada la extensión e(fx)clipse 3.8.0 o eso pienso ya que no me da las opciones de javaFX para obtener sus configuraciones, ni si quiera puedo ver la pestaña de design ni nada, es cómo si directamente no existiera JavaFX en mi computadora.

La verdad estuve probando un montón de formas, y comprobé varias veces que en el BuildPath, en las librerías de usuario estén añadidos los .jar necesarios para su uso, sin embargo, no puedo configurar nada de JavaFX ya que no aparece su pestaña en preferencias ni en ningún lugar.

En los tutoriales y documentos que leí, vi que a las personas que lo tienen correctamente instalado les aparece entre una de estas opciones "JavaFX" al crear querer crear un nuevo proyecto y darle a "other":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las preferencias, cuando quiero buscar las configuraciones de JavaFX, tampoco tengo la opción, por lo que no puedo configurar el SceneBuilder para que se asocie a Eclipse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sus respuestas, y cualquier cosa que necesiten una explicación más precisa del proceso de instalación o de otra cosa estoy al tanto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que primero tener todas las libreria de javafx en una carpeta de facil acceso y que no tenga restricciones del windows en caso de usarla.

luego debes añadir la libreria a tu eclipse.
luego tienes que configurar para activar los modulos de javafx
Run -> Run Configurations...  -> Java Application
--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-21\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

pero vas a agregar todos los modulos...en este ejemplo solo tienes controls y fxml pero agrega todos los que estan en la carpeta que descargastes de javafx

Aqui te dejo un link bien descriptiva.
[image: Documentación]

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/