# Como puedo distribuir una aplicacion de javafx desarrollada con netbeans

Tags: javafx

tengo un problema que llevo dias sin solucionar, soy algo nuevo en el uso de JavaFX y he estado buscando pero no encuentro nada que logre explicar el problema.

**El problema:** Cuando ejecuto la aplicacion desde Netbeans me ejecuta perfectamente, y en el momento que le doy limpiar y construir y voy a la carpeta donde lo almaceno y lo abro, no pasa nada, es como si nunca la intetara abrir. Por favor ayudenme con esto. Incluso pense que era mi proyecto y cree un nuevo proyecto con el codigo por defecto y me hace lo mismo, si alguno me pudiera explicar como hacer para distribuir la aplicacion y que funcione me seria de gran ayuda porque de lo contrario voy a tener que hacer todo el proyecto en otro lenguaje y no es lo que quiero, Ayudenme por favor.

A ver cuándo me refiero a lo abro es que busco la carpeta dist de mi proyecto y allí ejecutó el .jar que se generó, presionando doble click en él.

El codigo de las clases son los siguientes

**Clase principal**

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

**Codigo de la ventana**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Codigo del controlador**

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private Label label;
    
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
    
}
```

Comment: Hola Alain, bienvenido, cuando decis "lo abro", te referís a que intentas ejecutar el archivo **.jar** generado en la pre compilación via consola?, si es así, edita tu pregunta, y agrega el código de como lo estás haciendo, debería ser algo como **java -jar nombreAplicacion.jar**.

Comment: ya reedite la pregunta, es que tuve que hacer una cuenta para eso, a lo que me refiero es a que busco la carpeta dist de mi proyecto y alli doy doble click en el .jar generado

Comment: Que sistema operativo usas?, si es "Windows", no puedo aportar mucho, en teoría debería funcionar, si es "Linux", o bien lo ejecutas desde un terminal como te indiqué, o bien creas un lanzador.

Comment: Aqui puedes revisar esta solución que di a otro desarrollador.
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/604818/65242